# How to code edit points from postbit for vBulletin (Forum staff only)?

Tags: php, plugins, vbulletin

I am trying to a button that allows the staff (or the usergroups that have permission) to see that button visible on member's postbit legacy, and by clicking that they can edit the "points" or "currency" right there on the spot. Once a new value has been added it is updated in users table column points. I am using vBShop - DragonByte Tech for the points system, and was only able to find a code for myBB forums, not for vBulletin.

[image: a busy cat]

```
<?php

if(!defined("IN_MYBB"))
{
    die("Direct initialization of this file is not allowed.<br /><br />Please make sure IN_MYBB is defined.");
}

function newpoints_edit_info()
{
    return array(
    "name"          => "Newpoints Edit",
    "description"   => "Allows you to edit newpoints of any user.",
    "website"       => "http://yaldaram.com",
    "author"        => "Yaldaram",
    "authorsite"    => "http://yaldaram.com",
    "version"       => "0.2",
    "compatibility" => "14*,16*"
);

}
function newpoints_edit_install()
{
    global $db, $mybb;

    $newpoints_edit_group = array(
    "gid"           => "NULL",
    "name"          => "newpoints_edit",
    "title"         => "Newpoints Edit",
    "description"   => "Settings for the plugin.",
    "disporder"     => "1",
    "isdefault"     => "no",
);
$db->insert_query("settinggroups", $newpoints_edit_group);
$gid = $db->insert_id();

$newpoints_edit_setting_1 = array(
    "sid"           => "NULL",
    "name"          => "newpoints_edit_power",
    "title"         => "Power",
    "description"   => "Select Yes if you really wants this plugin to run.",
    "optionscode"   => "yesno",
    "value"         => "1",
    "disporder"     => "1",
    "gid"           => intval($gid),
);

$db->insert_query("settings", $newpoints_edit_setting_1);

$newpoints_edit_setting_2 = array(
    "sid"           => "NULL",
    "name"          => "newpoints_edit_group",
    "title"         => "MOD_Usergroups",
    "description"   => "Specify Usergroup IDs you wish to allow them to edit Newpoints.(Usually Moderators and Admins) Separate with , if more then.",
    "optionscode"   => "text",
    "value"         => "3,4",
    "disporder"     => "2",
    "gid"           => intval($gid),
);

$db->insert_query("settings", $newpoints_edit_setting_2);

$newpoints_edit_setting_3 = array(
    "sid"           => "NULL",
    "name"          => "newpoints_edit_self",
    "title"         => "Self_Editing",
    "description"   => "Would you like to allow above usergroups to edit their own Newpoints ?",
    "optionscode"   => "yesno",
    "value"         => "1",
    "disporder"     => "3",
    "gid"           => intval($gid),
);

$db->insert_query("settings", $newpoints_edit_setting_3);

rebuild_settings();

// Insert Templates
require MYBB_ROOT."/inc/adminfunctions_templates.php";
$template = array(
    "title"     => "newpoints_edit_page",
    "template"  => '<html>
<head>
<title>{$mybb->settings[\\\'bbname\\\']} - {$lang->edit_newpoints}</title>
{$headerinclude}
</head>
<body>
{$header}
<form action="newpoints.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="input">
<input type="hidden" name="my_post_key" value="{$mybb->post_code}" />
<table border="0" cellspacing="{$theme[\\\'borderwidth\\\']}" cellpadding="    {$theme[\\\'tablespace\\\']}" class="tborder">
<tr>
<td class="thead" colspan="2"><strong>{$lang->edit_newpoints_of} {$user_username}</strong>    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="trow1" width="25%">
<strong>{$lang->current_newpoints}</strong>
</td>
<td class="trow1" width="75%">
<i>{$user_newpoints}</i><br />
<span class="smalltext">{$lang->edit_using_form}</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="trow2" width="25%">
<strong>{$lang->edit_form}</strong>
</td>
<td class="trow2" width="75%">
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="points" size="40" maxlength="85" value="{$user_newpoints}" tabindex="1" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="thead" colspan="2">
<div style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="{$lang->submit}" tabindex="4" accesskey="s" /></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_edit" />
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="{$mybb->input[\\\'uid\\\']}" />
<input type="hidden" name="do_uid" value="{$mybb->user[\\\'uid\\\']}" />
</form>
{$footer}
</body>
</html>',
        "sid"       => -1
    );
    $db->insert_query("templates", $template);

    find_replace_templatesets("postbit", "#".preg_quote('{$post[\'newpoints_postbit\']}')."#i", '{\$post[\'newpoints_postbit\']} {\$post[\'newpoints_edit\']}');
    find_replace_templatesets("postbit_classic", "#".preg_quote('{$post[\'newpoints_postbit\']}')."#i", '{\$post[\'newpoints_postbit\']}{\$post[\'newpoints_edit\']}');
}

function newpoints_edit_is_installed()
{
    global $db;
    $query = $db->simple_select("settinggroups", "COUNT(*) as rows", "name='newpoints_edit'");
    $rows = $db->fetch_field($query, "rows");
    if($rows > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

function newpoints_edit_activate()
{
}

function newpoints_edit_deactivate()
{
}

function newpoints_edit_uninstall()
{
    global $db, $mybb;
    require MYBB_ROOT."/inc/adminfunctions_templates.php";
    find_replace_templatesets("postbit", "#".preg_quote('{$post[\'newpoints_edit\']}')."#i", '', 0);
    find_replace_templatesets("postbit_classic", "#".preg_quote('{$post[\'newpoints_edit\']}')."#i", '', 0);

    $db->query("DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."templates WHERE title='newpoints_edit_page'");
    $db->query("DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."settinggroups WHERE name='newpoints_edit'");
    $db->query("DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."settings WHERE name='newpoints_edit_power'");
    $db->query("DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."settings WHERE name='newpoints_edit_group'");
    rebuild_settings();
}

$plugins->add_hook("postbit", "newpoints_edit");
function newpoints_edit(&$post)
{
global $mybb, $lang, $templates;
$power = $mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_power'];
$groups = explode(",",$mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_group']);
$self_editing = $mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_self'];
if ($power != "0")
{
    $lang->load("newpoints_edit");
    if (in_array($mybb->user['additionalgroups'],$groups) || in_array($mybb->user['usergroup'],$groups) && $self_editing != "1" && $post['uid'] == $mybb->user['uid'])
    {
        $post['newpoints_edit'] = '';
    }
    elseif (in_array($mybb->user['usergroup'],$groups) || in_array($mybb->user['additionalgroups'],$groups))
    {
        $post['newpoints_edit'] = '[<a href="newpoints.php?action=edit&amp;uid='.$post['uid'].'">'.$lang->edit_newpoints_postbit.'</a>]';
    }
    }
}

$plugins->add_hook("newpoints_begin", "newpoints_edit_begin");
function newpoints_edit_begin()
{
    global $db, $mybb, $lang, $templates, $theme, $header, $footer, $headerinclude,     $newpoints_edit_page;

    $action = $mybb->input['action'];
$lang->load("newpoints_edit");
if ($action == "edit")
{
    $power = $mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_power'];
    if ($power != "1")
    {
        error($lang->newpoints_disabled);
    }

    $groups = explode(",",$mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_group']);
    if (!in_array($mybb->user['usergroup'],$groups) && !in_array($mybb->user['additionalgroups'],$groups))
    {
        error($lang->error_no_permission);
    }

    $self_editing = $mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_self'];
    $uid = intval($mybb->input['uid']);
    if ($self_editing != "1" && $uid == $mybb->user['uid'])
    {
        error($lang->no_permission_self_editing);
    }

    add_breadcrumb($lang->edit_newpoints, "newpoints.php?action=edit");

    $user = get_user($uid);
    $user_newpoints = intval($user['newpoints']);
    $user_username = htmlspecialchars_uni($user['username']);

    eval("\$newpoints_edit_page = \"".$templates->get("newpoints_edit_page")."\";");
    output_page($newpoints_edit_page);
}
elseif ($action == "do_edit")
{
    // Verify incoming post request.
    verify_post_check($mybb->input['my_post_key']);

    $power = $mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_power'];
    if ($power != "1")
    {
        error($lang->newpoints_disabled);
    }

    $groups = explode(",",$mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_group']);
    if (!in_array($mybb->user['usergroup'],$groups) && !in_array($mybb->user['additionalgroups'],$groups))
    {
        error($lang->error_no_permission);
    }

    $self_editing = $mybb->settings['newpoints_edit_self'];
    $uid = intval($mybb->input['uid']);
    if ($self_editing != "1" && $uid == $mybb->user['uid'])
    {
        error($lang->no_permission_self_editing);
    }

    $uid = intval($mybb->input['uid']);

    $updates =  array(
        "newpoints" => floatval($mybb->input['points'])
    );
    $db->update_query("users", $updates, "uid='{$uid}'");
    redirect("member.php?action=profile&amp;uid={$uid}", $lang->newpoints_edited_success);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that does exact same thing: http://www.dragonbyte-tech.com/product/40-vbcredits-ii-deluxe/